# The pipeline script written to tranfer the pipeline project from Slave to Master in Jenkins?Master(Windows server) and Slave(windows local)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins, I have build a pipeline project on Master and given Agent label Slave in the script where the project is build. I want to transfer this build from Slave to Master. I am not able to find the script to transfer this process as i am using  Windows for both master and slave.My Master is on Windows server(i.e. VM) and Slave is on Local Windows machine.Can someone please help me to find this as I am new for the Jenkins.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I want to transfer this build from Slave to Master"? The build is triggered on Master, runs on Slave, and its results (artifacts) are archived on master. If you want the build to run on Master, you should change the label to the one of Master.

Comment: When we keep label to the slave then we get result in slave after that if we want that result in Master what we should do?